# Visualforce Page displaying case count as per case category, On clicking each category I want to get a detailed view of the cases. How?

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce, sfdc

I have a visualforce page that displays the cases as per categorization(ex - Complaint, feedback etc) and beside each categorization the count of open cases of the category for the particular account. (Ex - Complaint 10, Feedback 5)

Now I want to provide a detailed view of the said 10 cases on clicking the count (ex complaint - 10) on clicking 10.

How to achieve this?

I have used Apex:column to display the case category and count in output link. On clicking this count how do i show the said 10 cases in detail view. Maybe on same VF page or redirect to another page? Which one will be better and how to implement. Any suggestions,Ideas with sample code will be highly helpful. (VF + Controller)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the onclick attribute beside each case or use the anchor tag like this `<a href='/recordid'>case name</a>` so when u click you are just open to a single and details of the single case.
To print the 10 case use `<apex:reapeat>` tag which can be helpful for iteration the 10 cases
hope it might help you.